# Terraform, can a resource be passed as a variable into a module?

Tags: terraform

I'm just getting to grips with Terraform (so apologies if this is a stupid question).

I'm setting up an azure vnet with a set of subnets, each subnet has a routing table that sends traffic via a firewall.

It looks like the subnet and route table combination would make a good re-useable module.

By convention, I'd like to create the subnet and the route table in the same resource group and location as the parent vnet.

If I provide all the values needed in the module as individual values, the module works ok :)

What I'd rather do is effectively pass the resource that represents the parent vnet into the module as a "parameter" and have the module read things like the resource group name, location and vnet name directly from the vnet resource, so that:
 - I type less (I create the module instance with just the vnet, rather than seperate values for vnet name, resource group name and location)
 - it removes the opportunity for error when setting the location and resource group names on the route table and subnet (if I read the values from the parent vnet in the module then the values will be the same as the parent vnet)

Currently the module variables are defined as:

```
variable "parent-vnet-name" {}

variable "parent-vnet-resource-group-name" {}

variable "parent-vnet-location" {}

variable "subnet-name" {
  type = "string"
}

variable "subnet-address-prefix" {}

variable "firewall-ip-private" {}
```

and the module as:

```
resource "azurerm_route_table" "rg-mgt-network__testtesttest" {
   name                = "${var.subnet-name}"
  location            = "${var.parent-vnet-location}"
  resource_group_name = "${var.parent-vnet-resource-group-name}"

  route {
    name                   = "Default"
    address_prefix         = "0.0.0.0/0"
    next_hop_type          = "VirtualAppliance"
    next_hop_in_ip_address = "${var.firewall-ip-private}"
  }
}
```

Really what I'd like to do is more like variables:

```
variable "parent-vnet" {}

variable "subnet-name" {
  type = "string"
}

variable "subnet-address-prefix" {}

variable "firewall-ip-private" {}
```

with module doing something like:

```
resource "azurerm_route_table" "rg-mgt-network__testtesttest" {
  name                = "${var.subnet-name}"
  location            = "${var.parent-vnet.location}"
  resource_group_name = "${var.parent-vnet.resource-group-name}"

  route {
    name                   = "Default"
    address_prefix         = "0.0.0.0/0"
    next_hop_type          = "VirtualAppliance"
    next_hop_in_ip_address = "${var.firewall-ip-private}"
  }
}
```

I've played around with a variety of things (such as trying to pass the vnet without specifying an attribute name (validation failure) or using a data source to pull back the vnet (the data sources doesn't have the resource group info) ) but haven't got anywhere so I'm wondering if I've missed something?

Cheers, Andy

Comment: Can you share your code so far? If you have a few different alternative show a minimal example of each and hwy they don't work for you.

Comment: Examples added. Cheers, Andy

Comment: Are you creating the route table and the virtual network at the same time? Or do you build them both with separate apply commands?

Comment: new subnets will be added over time - so they will be seperate apply commands

Comment: There doesn't seem to be an obvious link between the route table and the virtual network in your example (and I don't know Azure well) but are you not just passing in the resource group name and location that the virtual network happens to be in? But then I don't understand why the route table resource even needs the location specifying instead of extracting it from the resource group and simplifying the API.

Comment: Ahh, I could just look up the resource group as a data item (which from the azure doco appears to return the data I need - I'll give that a go. The link between the vnet and the route table is via the subnet, which I didnt include in the example (my bad, sorry).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Edit: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/57963406/866021 for an updated answer*

This isn't currently possible - according to the [Terraform Creating Modules page](https://www.terraform.io/docs/modules/create.html), a module's input variables can only be standard variable types: `string`, `list`, and `map`.

I've encountered this same use case and have had to provide large lists of inputs to modules, which isn't ideal but seems to be the current state of the world.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I was hoping there might be a way to convert a resource to a map and use the map as the variable value but it only seems to be possible to get a list of resource attributes.

Comment: I'm just learning (so I might not know what I'm talking about), but I got it working by specifying the variable type (in the module) as string, then just shoving a resource in there anyway and using it.

Answer (score 55):

This is possible with terraform > 0.12. You can use the `object` type, but you have to explicitly list fields that you use within your module.

```
# module's variables.tf
variable "parent_vnet" {
  # List each field in `azurerm_route_table` that your module will access
  type = object({
    name = string
    location = string
    resource_group_name = string
  })
} 

# caller
resource "azurerm_route_table" "my_parent_vnet" {
  # ...
}
module "my-module" {
  parent_vnet = azurerm_route_table.my_parent_vnet
}
```

Comment: you can activate YOLO mode by setting `type = any`

Answer (score 5):

If you want to avoid passing long lists of attributes of other resources you can use the `data` resources to avoid that.

Say you need all resources "provider" attributes within a module "consumer", pass in an identifier of the data source and then fetch all attributes using the data source within the module.

```
resource "producer" {
id = "id"
}

module "consumer" {
 second-module-id = resource.producer.id
}
```

Within the "consuming" module you can now call access all attributes of the "producer" using the data source (provided your cloud provider has a data source):

```
data "producer-data" {
id = second-module-id
}

resource "resource" {
  prop1 = data.prop1
  prop2 = data.prop2
  ...
}
```

Comment: We've started using the "data" resources and they are useful, however you can't use them for resources you are creating "in the same run". We've pretty much settled on either referencing the resources directly (if they are in the same state) or using a Tf remote state datasource to reference the properties directly in a different state file.

Comment: What you could do when using "data", is specify the resources that you want to pass to the module in a "depends_on" block within the "module" block. This allows Terraform to create all the resources that the module depends on first, and then use them within the module as "data".

Comment: Just for the record - the depends_on doesn't solve the problem as the whole thing crashes already when planning. At least when module uses for_each to iterate over the data.